# PdfReader of itext7 is not working in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

This is my code

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader;
...
...
try{
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/Users/Warrior/Documents/1.pdf");
}catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTree();
}
```

And I import pdfxfa-2.0.1.jar file in eclipse.
But not proceed in `new PdfReader`.
And It is not caught in the catch clause and not print error.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding another more general exception to see if there is an error, i.e.

```java
try{
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("..."); // The path to your pdf document
   // What do you want to achieve with the PdfReader instance here?
   // Do some action with your reader. You don't need to assign without using it
   // to see what is happening.
} catch(IOException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

If still the exception is not thrown, and caught by the `Exception` then you can blame the `PdfReader`.

You cannot really tell where the problem is without you showing how you're invoking methods of the `reader`. Merely assigning the reader does not mean the `PdfReader` is not working just because no error is thrown.

Comment: Sometimes it may even be necessary to catch `Throwable`.

Comment: I fixed my issue, the problem is loading library in eclipse is wrong.